# Random box of images gallery

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript

Is there any ready built images gallery as shown in this link?
https://www257.americanexpress.com/openhome/booming.do?extlink=db-gabmd-2010booming_Digg

If I were to build it by retrieve from database contains links to images and display on each containers, would TileList be useful or any idea is appreciate as I'm will be using it for displaying Classifieds images.

Answer (score 1):

That looks like a custom component.

A TileList probably won't help because it will size all images in the same manner.  IUn the Amex sample you have inconsistent image sizes and some images are span multiple rows while others span multiple columns.  Also, sometimes there are three rows and sometimes it appears there are two.  All this makes it hard to componentize such a layout.

If you can define a consistent layout; you can easily expand/contract any images to fit that layout and that would make things easier.  Otherwise, I'd just hard code the placement inside a canvas.

Answer (score 0):

It's not random. Watch it long enough and the same layouts appear again and again, they just have a fair few of them.

You could do it by having the layout containers in a horizontal list (which have variable widths) and then randomly choose between the set of layouts for each layout container. Then fill each image holder in the layout container with the correct sized image.

It's certainly doable, and probably not in that much time.